# dj_database_url not properly finding heroku postgres db configurations

Tags: django, heroku

I am having a problem getting django to recognize my heroku postgres db. Usually the following configuration work fine, but for some reason it has stopped working on my most recent application.

In settings.py, I added the following code.

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
print DATABASES['default']
```

it prints out {'default':{}}

the heroku pg:info command returns what looks to be normal:

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 1
PG Version:  9.2.4
Created:     2013-08-06 15:40 UTC
Data Size:   6.3 MB
Tables:      0
Rows:        0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
```

When I go to use the database it returns

```
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured.
```

Any thoughts on why dj_database_url.config() is not properly parsing the database configurations?
Thank you for the thoughts.

**EDIT:**

Still don't know the reason for the above behavior, but I found a work around. I had to add the postgres db to the app before the initial push. For some reason it wasn't finding it if it was added after the first push.

Comment: Can you clarify what you did for your workaround?  Did you add something to your settings file?

Answer (score -1):

This should be your db settings

```
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://user:passwprd@host/db')
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
```